# How to use "Promise.then =>" outside of a conditional in Typescript

Tags: typescript, if-statement, asynchronous, promise

I'm writing a function in TypeScript that looks like this:

```
record_time():any {
    if (some_condition) {
        axios.post('api/time').then(() =>
            updateTimeDisplay()
        );
    } else {
        axios.put('api/time').then(() =>
            updateTimeDisplay()
        );
    }
}
```

And it works, but as you can see, I'm calling the same line, `updateTimeDisplay()`, regardless of the conditional. For conciseness, I'd like to know if there is a way to rewrite this so that I'd only write `updateTimeDisplay()` once. Tried something like below, but the code broke with this error: `Cannot find name 'then'.Vetur(2304)`

```
record_time():any {
    if (some_condition) {
        axios.post('api/time');
    } else {
        axios.put('api/time');
    }.then(() =>
      updateTimeDisplay()
    )
}
```

---

**[Update]** I realised it makes more sense for my case to change the structure like this (separate out `updateTimeDisplay` from `record_time`, and call both functions inside a different function):

```
async switch_button_status_record_time() {
    await this.switch_button_status();
    await this.record_time();
    updateTimeDisplay();
}

async record_time() {
    if (some_condition) {
        axios.post('api/time')
    } else {
        axios.put('api/time')
    }
}
```

However, this caused the code to break - sometimes `updateTimeDisplay` would not be called correctly. I was under the impression that lines with `await` would be called in order (`switch_button_status`, then `record_time`, then `updateTimeDisplay`). What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an assignment.

```
record_time():any {
  var apiPromise;
  if (some_condition) {
    apiPromise = axios.post('api/time');
  }else {
    apiPromise = axios.put('api/time');
  }

  apiPromise.then(() =>
    updateTimeDisplay()
  )
}
```

Or you can condense it to this:

```
var apiPromise = some_condition ? axios.post('api/time') : axios.put('api/time');
apiPromise.then(() => updateTimeDisplay());
```

Comment: Thank you, you were right! Could you check out my updated situation though - I tried using `async/await` instead and it is not working...

Comment: @Risa - In the new `record_time` you are not awaiting anything so it runs synchronously and does not return a promise. Add `await` in front of both calss (`axios.post` and `axios.put`). If you are still having trouble I recommend you start a new question, continuing/adding with multiple questions in one question in so is frowned upon.